# Does Scheduler take one core for itself?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am trying to automate database dump and it works like in script

```
sched = Scheduler()

@sched.cron_schedule(day_of_week='mon-fri', hour=13)
def dump():
    '''Dumps database with predefined data'''
    user = 'root'
    password = 'root'
    host = 'localhost'
    database = 'root_db'


    filestamp = time.strftime('%Y-%m-%d-%I:%M')
    os.popen("mysqldump -u %s -p%s -h %s -e --opt -c %s | gzip -c > %s.gz" % (user, password, host, database, database + "_" + filestamp))

    print "\n-- please have a the dump file in " + database + "_" + filestamp + ".gz --"


if __name__ == "__main__":
    sched.start()
    while True:
        pass
```

Also I have 4 cores without hyperthreading on computer and I have deployed 4 instances of Tornado.
My question is If I start script above does it gonna take one processor for self ?

Answer (score 0):

For the quanta of time that the code from the script executes, yes, it does take a core for itself.

A couple of things you should note though. The script seems to be launching a *mysqldump* program every 13th hour mon-fri. So, the scheduler script itself will only execute for a short while. After that the *mysqldump* program will run for as long as it does, and as and when it executes, it will occupy a core.

The script or the *mysqldump* program will not occupy the CPU for the entire duration that it runs. The CPU will be taken away from these when they are idle or perform IO or other wait operations. In general, the OS scheduler will share the cores among all the processes alive on the system (as and when they need it, based on the scheduling algorithm).

Also, the fragment of code:

```
while True:
    pass
```

It seems like it will spin. That will definitely burn the CPU. Maybe this is what you are seeing and really asking about. You don't want that. I would replace that with a *sleep* or some other wait operation (unless python is smart enough to optimize this to a wait operation on it's own).

```
while True:
    time.sleep(1000)
```